# need help looping rock, paper, scissors game properly

Tags: python, while-loop

I'm really new to coding and I have this rock paper scissors game loops 5 times like I want but it is not looping correctly through the code like I want it to. the computer only gives a random answer once and ignores all other answers entered.

`````
def get_choices():
    player_choice = input("Enter a choice (rock, paper, scissors): ")
    options = ["rock", "paper", "scissors"]
    computer_choice = random.choice(options)

    answers = {"player": player_choice, "computer": computer_choice}
    return answers


def check_win(player, computer):
    #    games_played = 0
    #    print("number of games played", str(games_played))
    #    print(f"You chose {player}, Computer chose {computer}")
    #    while games_played != 5:
    #        games_played += 1
    #        get_choices()
    #        print("number of games played", str(games_played))
    if player == computer:
        return "Its a tie"
    elif player == "rock":
        if computer == "scissors":
            return "rock smashes scissors! You win!"
        else:
            return "paper covers rock. you lose."
    elif player == "paper":
        if computer == "rock":
            return "paper covers rock! You win!"
        else:
            return "scissors cut paper. you lose."
    elif player == "scissors":
        if computer == "paper":
            return "scissors cut paper! You win!"
        else:
            return "rock beats scissors. you lose."


choices = get_choices()
result = check_win(choices["player"], choices["computer"])

while games_played != 5:
    games_played += 1
    get_choices()
    check_win(choices["player"], choices["computer"])
    print("number of games played", str(games_played))
    print(result)
else:
    print("\nend of game")````
`````

Comment: When you call `check_win` in your loop, you don't do anything with the result it returns, so you're always just going to print the result from that first round.

Comment: Same thing with `get_choices`.

Comment: Each time you run the function, you want to update the results. So if the loop runs 5 times, but the result is only declared once the first time, then it will be the same answer for all times.

Comment: Honestly, for a simple problem like this, it may be best to use ChatGPT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tested your code. I found multiple bugs in it, but they are easy to fix. I have listed them and their solutions.

#### 1. Loop variable

You are not defining the variable for the while loop, `games_played`.

**Fix 1:**

```
games_played = 0

# While loop goes here ...
```

#### 2. Updating variables inside the loop

> computer only gives a random answer once...

This is because you are declaring the variables `choices` and `result` before the while loop and then using their values inside the loop without updating them.
Also, you are calling `get_choices()` and `check_win()` functions inside the loop, and the return values from these functions are not being assigned to any variable.

The fix is to move the variables out of the while loop and put them inside.

**Fix 2:**

```
# We remove these lines that run before the loop.
# choices = get_choices()
# result = check_win(choices["player"], choices["computer"])

while games_played != 5:
    games_played += 1

    # Declare choices inside the loop.
    choices = get_choices()

    # Declare result inside the loop
    result = check_win(choices["player"], choices["computer"])

    print("number of games played", str(games_played))
    print(result)
else:
    print("\nend of game")
```

### Complete code

```
def get_choices():
    player_choice = input("Enter a choice (rock, paper, scissors): ")
    options = ["rock", "paper", "scissors"]
    computer_choice = random.choice(options)

    answers = {"player": player_choice, "computer": computer_choice}
    return answers


def check_win(player, computer):
    #    games_played = 0
    #    print("number of games played", str(games_played))
    #    print(f"You chose {player}, Computer chose {computer}")
    #    while games_played != 5:
    #        games_played += 1
    #        get_choices()
    #        print("number of games played", str(games_played))
    if player == computer:
        return "Its a tie"
    elif player == "rock":
        if computer == "scissors":
            return "rock smashes scissors! You win!"
        else:
            return "paper covers rock. you lose."
    elif player == "paper":
        if computer == "rock":
            return "paper covers rock! You win!"
        else:
            return "scissors cut paper. you lose."
    elif player == "scissors":
        if computer == "paper":
            return "scissors cut paper! You win!"
        else:
            return "rock beats scissors. you lose."

games_played = 0

while games_played != 5:
    games_played += 1
    choices = get_choices()
    result = check_win(choices["player"], choices["computer"])
    print("number of games played", str(games_played))
    print(result)
else:
    print("\nend of game")
```

*I did not add imports in the code, im guesing you already have them!*

Answer (score 2):

I kept the base of your code but changed some of the structure. I also added a piece of code that continues after 5 matches if they are tied.

```
import random

def get_choices():
    player_choice = input("Enter a choice (rock, paper, scissors): ")
    options = ["rock", "paper", "scissors"]
    computer_choice = random.choice(options)

    answers = {"player": player_choice, "computer": computer_choice}
    return answers


def check_win(player, computer):
    if player == computer:
        return "Its a tie"
    elif player == "rock":
        if computer == "scissors":
            return "rock smashes scissors! You win!"
        else:
            return "paper covers rock. you lose."
    elif player == "paper":
        if computer == "rock":
            return "paper covers rock! You win!"
        else:
            return "scissors cut paper. you lose."
    elif player == "scissors":
        if computer == "paper":
            return "scissors cut paper! You win!"
        else:
            return "rock beats scissors. you lose."


def play_rps():
    games_played = 0
    want_2_play = 5
    player_wins = 0
    computer_wins = 0
    win = "win"
    lose = "lose"
    print()
    while games_played < want_2_play:
        print(f"Match: {games_played + 1}")
        weapons = get_choices()
        player = weapons.get('player')
        computer = weapons.get('computer')

        battle_result = check_win(player, computer)
        print(battle_result)

        if win in battle_result:
            player_wins += 1
        if lose in battle_result:
            computer_wins += 1

        print()   
        games_played += 1

    
    while computer_wins == player_wins:

        print(f"Match: {games_played + 1}")
        weapons = get_choices()
        player = weapons.get('player')
        computer = weapons.get('computer')
        battle_result = check_win(player, computer)
        print(battle_result)

        if win in battle_result:
            player_wins += 1
        if lose in battle_result:
            computer_wins += 1

        print()  
        games_played += 1

    print("Game Over")
    print()
    print(f"The Computer won {computer_wins} matches")
    print(f"You won {player_wins} matches")
    print()
    if player_wins > computer_wins:
        print("You won the game")
    else:
        print("You lost the game")



play_rps()
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned in the comments, maybe this is the solution (though I don't know how your whole file looks)

`````
games_played = 0; 
choices = get_choices()
result = check_win(choices["player"], choices["computer"])

while games_played != 5:
    games_played += 1 # you updated your games_played variable so you should do the same for choices
    choices = get_choices() # now choices is updated with the new user input and computer random choice 
    result = check_win(choices["player"], choices["computer"]) # and then update the result 
    print("number of games played", str(games_played))
    print(result)
else:
    print("\nend of game")````
`````